# Negating Regex for Required field

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a regex below which will check for required field
Currently this returns true when someone enters text in a fields and false when the fields are empty, but i want to rewrite the same regex to get the opposite of it.

[Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/KFCHM/)

```
^[\s\t\r\n]*\S+
```

I dont want to negate the return value, instead retrun value must be negated by regex.

Comment: Seems like an odd request but would `/^$/` achieve what you want? see https://regex101.com/r/DA9ISK/1

Comment: Or maybe you want `/^[\s\t\r\n]*$/` see https://regex101.com/r/DA9ISK/3

Answer (score 1):

Your question is kinda weird because if you want a regex to match when a field is empty you can just use:

```
^$
```

But you were talking about negating your regex, so if you want to match oposite you can use:

```
^[^\s\t\r\n]*\s+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can negate it by using `(?!)`

```
^(?![\s\t\r\n]*\S+)
```

See here https://regex101.com/r/DA9ISK/2